# JS Get Classname of Class

Tags: javascript, class, oop

How do i get the own classname of a class in javascript?

I implemented a method and i want to catch an error by logging the error with a message in which class the error happened.

My current solution is *dirty*: I save the class-name in the *constructor*

```
constructor{
    this.className = 'MyClass';}
```

However, i think there must be a better solution, something like *Object.protytpe.XXX*

I googled and searched in Stackoverflow, but all the answers didnt result in my desired output.

May somebody have an idea?

Comment: Given the value is pretty static, you might as well hardcode it in the method.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

- `this.constructor.name` from inside an instance method of your class
- `obj.constructor.name` where obj is an instance of your class
- `klass.name` where klass is a reference to your class